# Finding another Solution to the Diffusion Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am currently trying to find another solution to the Diffusion Equation through another method. Now, the problem begins with showing that given the solution:
$$u(x,t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(x-y,t)g(y) dy\>\>\>\>(*)$$ solves the Heat Equation $u_t=u_{xx}, \>\>u(x,0)=g(x)$, where $\Phi$ is the Heat Kernel:
$$\Phi(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}e^{-x^2/4ct}$$
We have the following questions:

> 1) Show that if $u(x,t)$ is a smooth solution to the Diffusion Equation $u_t=u_{xx}$, then so is $u(\lambda x, \lambda^2 t)$
>
> 2)This scaling invariance suggests that the ratio $x^2/t$ might play an important role. We look for a solution of the form $v(x^2/t) = u(x,t)$.
>
> 3) Show that if $u$ with the form $(*)$ solves the PDE $u_t=u_{xx}$, then $v$ solves the ODE $4sv''(s)+(2+s)v'(s)=0$.
>
> 4)Find $v(s)$, the general solution to the ODE.
>
> 5)Show that if $u(x,t)$ is a $C^\infty$ solution to the Diffusion Equation, then so is $u_x(x,t)$. Use this fact to differentiate $u(x,t)=v(x^2/t)$ with respect to $x$ and discover a new solution to the Diffusion Equation.

Now, I have shown that $u_{\lambda}(x,t) = u(\lambda x,\lambda ^2 t)$ solves the Heat Equation as well, along with being smooth. Then I considered $u(x,t)=v(s)$, where $s=\frac{x^2}{t}$. This gave me the ODE:
$$4sv''(s)+(2+s)v'(s)=0$$
Solving this ODE, I found:
$$v(s) = c_1\int\frac{e^{-s/4}}{\sqrt s} ds+c_2\>\>\>\>(1)$$
Where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are just constants. I also know that the complete solution is supposed to be along the lines of:$$u(x,t) =\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{4ct}}}e^{-y^2}dy\>\>\>\>\>\>(2)$$
But how in the world do I get $(2)$ from $(1)$? I tried substituting in $s=\frac{x^2}{t}$ and it didn't work. If someone could enlighten me it would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You didn't specify any data in your problem. However, I'm guessing that as
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} u(x,t) &= \lim_{s \to \infty} v(s) \\ 
&= c_{2} \quad (1) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \quad (2)
\end{align}
that you are given $\lim_{x \to \infty} u = 1/2$? Also, [this is a good example of why you need to choose a favourable self similarity variable](http://www.lmm.jussieu.fr/~lagree/COURS/M2MHP/SSS.pdf) (see section 2.2).

Comment: @Mattos the only data specified was given by $u(x,0)=g(x)$

Comment: Then perhaps you could make the substitution $s/4 = y^{2}$, use that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-y^{2}} dy = \sqrt{\pi}$$ and notice that the integrand is even and the domain of integration symmetric, hence the integral over $[0, \infty) = \dots$

Comment: @Mattos, so I have simplified my integral into the form: $$v(y) = c_1\int^{x/\sqrt{4t}}_0e^{-y^2} dy+c_2$$But now the only hint in the question is given by either $u(x,t)=u(\lambda x,\lambda ^2 t)=v(s)$, and that if $u$ solves the Diffusion Equation, so should $u_x$, and use this to solve for the constants. How would I do this?

Comment: Can you write out the entire question in your post? You need to give me all the information specified, otherwise we'll be going back and forward like this for ages. Also, in answer to your question, by the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) we have the $$u_{x} = 4c_{1} \frac{e^{-x^{2}/t}}{\sqrt{t}}$$ though without knowing the full question or it's requirements, I'm not sure how this would help you.

Comment: @Mattos I will update it tonight with all the parts added.

Comment: @Mattos I have updated the question so it shows each part.